# Why is the variance of $F_n(x)$ is $F(X)-F(x)^2$?

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics

For iid random samples $X_1,\dots, X_n$ with CDF $F(x)=P(X\le x)$. Define the empirical CDF
$F_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n I(X_i\le x)$. Why is the variance of $F_n(x)$ is $F(X)-F(x)^2$? Then from CLT we have $\sqrt{n}(F_n(x)-F(x))\to N(0, F(x)(1-F(x)).$

We know that $E F_n(x)=F(x)$, then

$$
Var(F_n(x))=E F_n^2(x)-(F(x))^2=?
$$

Comment: What is $F(X)$?

Comment: Note that $\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{\{X_i \leq x\}}\sim \text{Binomial}(n,F(x))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, variance of $F_n(X)$ is $\frac  1 n [F(x)-F(x)^{2}]$.

$EF_n(X)=\frac  1 n  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} P(X_I \leq X)=F(x)$ and

$EF_n(X)^{2}=\frac  1{n^{2}} \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n} P(X_i \leq x, X_j \leq x)$. Splitting the sum into the parts where $i=j$ and the one where $i \neq j$ we get $EF_n(X)^{2}=\frac  1{n^{2}} [nF(x)+n(n-1)F(x)^{2}]$ since $X_i,X_j$ are independent fir $i \neq j$.

Hence, the variance of $F_n(X)$ is $EF_n(X)^{2}-(EF_n(X))^{2}=\frac  1 n [F(x)-F(x)^{2}]$.